# Workflow rule and chunk size

Tags: trigger, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

There is a workflow rule with time-dependent action for Lead.
And there is an update trigger for Lead.

For example, it is going to do an update for 2000 leads.
How many leads will be passed to trigger at once? All lead or it will pass it in chunks?

Comment: Triggers process records at a maximum "chunk size" or in "batches" of 200 records at a time.

Comment: and be aware of this as well in case you have a recursive trigger guard implemented with static variables - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091mJIAQ

Comment: I tried to simulate stated scenario. I created a workflow which will set a time dependent action after 1 hour of creation. I created 3K such records and all 3K time dependent actions got scheduled.
But every hour only 50 time dependent actions got executed. In trigger I got 50 records chunk.

Comment: @kiran-machhewar I got > 100 (I caught SOWL limit exception), maybe that depends on SF instance type

Comment: @John Yes that might be the case. So it would be best to consider that there would be updates in bulk but now how many records would be there we can not identify that. Normally limit of time dependent actions is 1000 per hour. This could be raised to higher limits. In those scenarios salesforce could send more than 100. Yes it would have been good to know what could be max no of records salesforce performs action in bulk.